# Powershell build script - Execute it from any machine

Tags: powershell, build-automation, powershell-2.0

We have our build script written in powershell. It is there in dedicated build machine.

Now i want to execute the powershell script from my machine without login to build machine via mstsc.

Moreover no one else should be executing the build script except me.

Is it possible to invoke my powershell script in build machine from any other machine?

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to enable ps-remoting on the dedicated build machine

You can do `Enable-PsRemoting` ( and / or `winrm quickconfig` )

Now you can do things like:

```
invoke-command -computer $buildBox -command { hostname }
```

So using `invoke-command`, you can run scripts on the remote box.

Comment: Buddy some one asked question to you in answer section

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **Powershell Remoting**: `http://powershellremoting.codeplex.com/`